# How can I get my javascript image onMouseOver code to work in an html image map?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get this code working for Chrome, Firefox and IE. Each link in the image map has to have its own image that should appear on hover. My main problem is that all the links are showing the same image instead of their own specific one.

Also, it only seems to work in Chrome :( why?

Please help if you can :)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3U8b/)

*Sample from html file*

```
<img src="images/Solutions_table.jpg" width="940" height="818" alt="Solutions Comparative table" usemap="tablemap">

<map name="tablemap" >

<script type = "text/javascript">
function show() {
    document.getElementById('pop').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
function hide() {
    document.getElementById('pop').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>

  <area id="pop" class="p1" href="minnow.html" shape="rect" coords="1,116,105,184" alt="Minnow" onMouseOver="show()" onMouseOut="hide()">
  <area id="pop" class="p2" href="guppie.html" shape="rect" coords="1,182,105,250" alt="Guppie" onMouseOver="show()" onMouseOut="hide()">
  <area id="pop" class="p3" href="blue marlin.html" shape="rect" coords="1,248,105,316" alt="blue marlin" onMouseOver="show()" onMouseOut="hide()">
  <area id="pop" class="p4" href="black marlin.html" shape="rect" coords="1,314,105,382" alt="black marlin" onMouseOver="show()" onMouseOut="hide()">
  <area id="pop" class="p5" href="baracuda.html" shape="rect" coords="1,381,105,450" alt="baracuda" onMouseOver="show()" onMouseOut="hide()">

</map>
```

*The Css*

```
#pop {
    display:block;
    width:506px;
    height:506px;
    z-index:110;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-701px;
    margin-left:105px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.p1 {
    content:url(images/minnow.jpg);
    display:block;
    width:506px;
    height:506px;
    z-index:110;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-701px;
    margin-left:105px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.p2 {
    content:url(images/guppie.jpg);
    display:block;
    width:506px;
    height:506px;
    z-index:110;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-701px;
    margin-left:105px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.p3 {
    content:url(images/blue marlin.jpg);
    display:block;
    width:506px;
    height:506px;
    z-index:110;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-701px;
    margin-left:105px;
    visibility:hidden

}

.p4 {
    content:url(images/black marlin.jpg);
    display:block;
    width:506px;
    height:506px;
    z-index:110;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-701px;
    margin-left:105px;
    visibility:hidden
}

.p5 {
    content:url(images/baracuda.jpg);
    display:block;
    width:506px;
    height:506px;
    z-index:110;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-701px;
    margin-left:105px;
    visibility:hidden
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: An ID needs to be unique. You can't have multiple `id="pop"`. Just do `onMouseOver="show(this)"` and your function `function show(element) { element.style.visibility = 'visible' }`

Comment: oh, but then that would mean i would have to have multiple instances of my javascript function and when i did that i ended up with the same issue: all the links display the same picture instead of an individual one.

Comment: lol sorry typed that before i saw the rest of you msg :)

Comment: I'm getting `show is not defined` on Google Chrome. I don't know why it's not defined, though.

Comment: could you possibly show me that in a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y3U8b/1/ it doesn't work in the fiddle but I guess it's because you have obstrusive js. You need to add the javascript right before the closing <body> tag, otherwise you're trying to work with elements that have not yet been created (.pop, in this case)

Comment: I was right. It's ok here: http://jsfiddle.net/y3U8b/2/

Comment: It's not because it's not right before the closing of the body tag (the element is made in a function, so that shouldn't be a problem), it's that the functions aren't defined when they're called since they're declared inside `window.onload` @JonasGrumann

Comment: That's both. On jsfiddle, calling js functions obstrusively without putting them in the window object won't work. But searching for dom elements before they're even created is another problem, unless, of course, you put the js in an onload callback

Comment: Yes, but since the DOM elements are searched for _in the functions_, the elements will be created by the time they're called. Your way works just as good, too, but it's just my personal preference to keep the JS separated. @JonasGrumann

Comment: You're right. It's everyone's preference to keep the js separated ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSFiddle, if you're going to call functions in events, you need to declare variables with `window.show` and `window.hide` because your script is put inside a `window.onload` method:

```
window.show = function() {
    document.querySelector('.pop').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

window.hide = function() {
    document.querySelector('.pop').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

If you want to, you can also change the wrap on the left side of the JSFiddle. The option `No wrap - in <body>` puts your script in the global scope, just before the closing of the body tag.